# How to run multiple files together on Refextract

Tags: python, python-3.x, reference, pdftotext

I'm a novice in python and I need to extract references from scientific literature. Following is the code I'm using

```
from refextract import extract_references_from_file

import pandas as pd

references = extract_references_from_file('1503.07589.pdf')

dfref = pd.DataFrame(references)

dfref.to_excel('./refs.xlsx')
```

**I can only extract references from a single file at a time using this command but I need to extract references from numerous files together. So, Please guide me whether is it possible and how to do it. Thank you so much!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/refextract/#refextract.extract_references_from_file) claim that extracted references are returned as a `dict`.

> Returns a dictionary with extracted references and stats.

This is not quite accurate;
a `list` of `dict`s is returned,
one dictionary per reference.

So you simply need to build up a longer list.

```
from refextract import extract_references_from_file

higgs_papers = ['1503.07589', '2008.05492']
references = []
for paper in higgs_papers:
    references.extend(extract_references_from_file(f'/tmp/{paper}.pdf'))
```

Now you have a bigger list, `references`, that you can turn into a bigger `df`.

---

You might also find [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) convenient:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('/tmp/*.pdf')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It did work but while converting it to the xls format, All the information of a one reference is in one cell like following

{'raw_ref': ['Berg, B.L., 2000. Qualitative research methods for the social sciences. Needham Heights:'], 'author': ['Berg, B.L.'], 'misc': ['Qualitative research methods for the social sciences. Needham Heights:'], 'year': ['2000']}

Whereas it was divided into different columns earlier like misc, author, raw_ref etc. 
I need it to be divided because it'll be used to create Network Diagrams. So, Is there any other way to achieve it.

Comment: Sorry! I made an edit just now, turning .append() into .extend(), so each element is an individual citation.